# Android relative layout positioning scale?

Tags: android

I think question is clear as you can see in the image. What I need to use for positioning these ImageViews correctly.
Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHzrN.png

The XML code, I'M using Relative Layout Should I use else Layout type ?;

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.natastudio.tictactoeblackboard.MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/woodfull">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/scoreboard"
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Player 1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="34dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Player 2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="34dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/backshort"
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="34dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView4" />

    <TextView
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="34dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView4" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/continueshort"
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView10"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView2" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/blackboard"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginBottom="192dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/lines"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/six"
        android:layout_below="@+id/three"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="11dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView10"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView10"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView10" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/one"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/six"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/six" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/two"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/two"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/two" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/four"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView10"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/five"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/five" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/five"
        android:layout_below="@+id/two"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/six"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/six" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/eight"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/seven"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/seven" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/nine"
        android:layout_below="@+id/six"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/eight"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/eight" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/seven"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/one"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/one" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: post your xml code.

Comment: I think you should use LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout.

Comment: Ok, I will try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following xml will display buttons in 3x3 grid

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/activity_next"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context="com.impiger.myapplication.NextActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Button 1"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Button 2"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Button 3"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Button 4"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Button 5"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Button 6"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:text="Button 7"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Button 8"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:text="Button 8"/>
```

Attached screen shot as result[image: Result screen]

Comment: But this is for full screen. I need this for half of my page.

Comment: Based on the height it will get adjusted dude.